# Json.NET's JsonConverter. Implementing custom converter

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I want to write a custom JsonConverter to read JSON files into an Dictionary Object.

It would be something like:

file.json -> `Dictionary<string, MyObject>`

file.json:

```
{
    "dictKey" : "stringValue with HELLO", ...
}
```

where MyObject is a class with a few values like:

```
string textValue;
bool HasHELLO;
```

Any idea how one would achieve this?

I'm trying to do this on Unity 5.3, so the NET version is limited to 3.5 (mostly).

Something like this, but obviously this wouldn't work unless I override the Jsonconverter and write my own:

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, MyObject>>(json);
```

Comment: Why do you need a _custom converter_?

Comment: I need the JSON file to be converted to "Dictionary<string, MyObject>"

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] for your problem?  I.e. some specific JSON you want to parse and the class you want to parse to?

Comment: Ok. What makes HasHello true or false? If the string contains the word or not?

Comment: Just for reference [`What is the version of .net in Unity 5?`](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/924021/what-is-the-version-of-net-in-unity-5.html)

Comment: @dbc it's already present.

Comment: @khlr Yep! that's all there is to it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: No it's different. That one is a simpler solution because it puts the string directly into the dictionary. My problem is that the dictionary contains a custom object.